# How to render a space in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component like this:

```
  <CustomerInfo
              key={customer.id}
              customerId={customer.id}
              customerName={customer.firstName + ' ' + customer.lastName}
  />
```

Is this the way to add a space to an expression? What could be a drawback?

Comment: Yes, that's how'd concatenate to string with a space in JavaScript. Or you could do `[customer.firstName, customer.lastName].join(' ')`. This has nothing to do with React.

Answer (score 0):

You can put any valid JavaScript expression inside the curly braces in JSX. After resolving the JS expression, React will return its value to the prop you are passing. So no downsides as such. Its good to go!

To handle situations when either one or both first and lastname are empty/undefined:

```
getFullName(fName, lName) {
return (fName ? (fName + ' ') : '' + lName ? lName : '').trim();
}

<CustomerInfo
              key={customer.id}
              customerId={customer.id}
              customerName={this.getFullName(customer.firstName, customer.lastName)}
  />
```

Comment: One quick caveat: JavaScript's normal rules on type coercion do indeed apply. You might get some strange results depending on your `customer` object. For example, `{firstName: 'Jane'}` will result in `'Jane undefined'`.

Comment: Yeah that may arise, in case you need to handle that you could write a utility for same. Check updated answer.